# Forward function calls to member variable

Tags: c++, c++17

I'm trying to make classes that follow a pattern, but trying to avoid using inheritance to solve the problem. But there is some common code that can be pulled into it's own class which can be reused. Like this:

```
class Common {
    public:
        int foo() {return 1;}
};

class A {
    public:
        // Expose Common's public methods
        int bar() {return 2;}
    private:
        Common common;
};

class B {
    public:
        // Expose Common's public methods
        int bar() {return 3;}
    private:
        Common common;
};

template<class... Ts> struct overloaded : Ts... { using Ts::operator()...; };
template<class... Ts> overloaded(Ts...) -> overloaded<Ts...>;

std::variant<A, B> variant = A{};
std::visit(overloaded {
        [](A a) { a.foo(); },
        [](B b) { b.foo(); },
}, variant);
```

Is there any way to achieve what I want without writing this biolerplate code?

```
int A::foo() { return common.foo(); } 
int B::foo() { return common.foo(); }
```

Comment: Why do you want to avoid inheritance?

Comment: if you don't use virtual methods inheritance has zero runtime overhead, so unless you have a good reason for avoiding inheritance, I suggest you use inheritance.

Comment: Yeah, I wanted to see if I could get away without inheritance, but looks like I have to use it

Comment: If you dislike _public_ inheritance because it is exposed to users as an "is-a relationship" then here is another option: You can choose _private_ inheritance and then type `public: using Common::foo;` in `A` and `B`. You can think of that private inheritance as an "is-implemented-in-terms-of relationship".

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to implement is typically called a mixin. See [What is a mixin, and why are they useful?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/533631/what-is-a-mixin-and-why-are-they-useful).

In C++, you typically either do:

- Inheritance (without dynamic dispatching)
- CRTP

See [Two different mixin patterns in C++. (mixin? CRTP?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26486456/two-different-mixin-patterns-in-c-mixin-crtp)

There are also other less glamorous solutions:

- Making the `common` member variable `public` or equivalent (requires changes to users)
- A macro, an `#include` or any sort of code generation that expands to whatever interface you need